# Signalr not working with Autofac and WebAPI + MVC + OWIN

Tags: asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller, signalr, owin, autofac

We are trying to start our Signalr Hub with Dependency Injection using Autofac but with no result yet.
MVC and Web Apis are working fine with DI.

Here the config files.

**Startup.cs**

```
[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(PNAME.WebUI.Startup))]
namespace PNAME.WebUI
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var config = new HttpConfiguration();

            // Register Routes
            WebApiConfig.Register(config);

            // Register dependencies
            //ConfigureDependencies(app, config);
            var container = DependencyConfiguration.Configure(app);
            SignalRConfiguration.Configure(app, container);
            MvcConfiguration.Configure(app, container);
            WebApiConfiguration.Configure(app, container, config);
            // Configure Authentication middleware
            ConfigureAuth(app, config);

            // configure Web API 
            app.UseWebApi(config);
        }
    }
}
```

**DependencyConfiguration.cs**

```
  public static class DependencyConfiguration
    {
        public static IContainer Configure(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();


            //Register any other components required by your code....
            builder.RegisterType<MainContext>().As<IApplicationDbContext>();

            builder.RegisterType<OneSignalNotificationService>().As<IPushNotificationService>();

            builder.RegisterType<LogService>().As<ILogger>();

            //Register SignalR Hub
            builder.RegisterHubs(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            //builder.RegisterType<ChatHub>().ExternallyOwned();

            //Register MVC Controllers
            builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

            //Register WebApi Controllers
            builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

            var container = builder.Build();
            app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
            return container;
        }
    }
```

**WebApiConfiguration.cs**

```
public class WebApiConfiguration
    {
        public static void Configure(IAppBuilder app, IContainer container, HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Set the dependency resolver for Web API.
            var webApiResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
            config.DependencyResolver = webApiResolver;

            //Configure Action Injection
            //config.InjectInterfacesIntoActions();

            app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);
        }
    }
```

**SignalRConfiguration.cs**

```
  public static class SignalRConfiguration
    {
        public static void Configure(IAppBuilder app, IContainer container)
        {
            //var config = new HubConfiguration();
            //config.Resolver = new AutofacDependencyResolver(container);
            //config.EnableDetailedErrors = true;

            //app.MapSignalR("/signalr", config);

            app.Map("/signalr", map =>
            {
                map.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);

                var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
                {
                    Resolver = new AutofacDependencyResolver(container),
                    EnableDetailedErrors = true
                };

                map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
            });
        }
    }
```

**MvcConfiguration.cs**

```
public class MvcConfiguration
    {
        public static void Configure(IAppBuilder app, IContainer container)
        {
            var mvcResolver = new Autofac.Integration.Mvc.AutofacDependencyResolver(container);
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(mvcResolver);

            app.UseAutofacMvc();
        }
    }
```

As for the `ChatHub` its **located in another project as class library** with different `namespace` as below

**ChatHub.cs**

```
namespace PNAME.BotServices.NotificationCenter.SignalR
{
    [HubName("ChatHub")]
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        private ILogger _logger;
        //private IChatMessageServices _chatMessageServices;
        private readonly ILifetimeScope _hubLifetimeScope;

        public ChatHub(ILifetimeScope lifetimeScope)
        {
            // Create a lifetime scope for the hub.
            _hubLifetimeScope = lifetimeScope.BeginLifetimeScope("AutofacWebRequest");

            // Resolve dependencies from the hub lifetime scope.
            _logger = _hubLifetimeScope.Resolve<ILogger>();
           // _chatMessageServices = _hubLifetimeScope.Resolve<IChatMessageServices>();

        }

        public bool SendMessage(INotificationMessage notificationMessage)
        {
           //Some code here
        }
        public override Task OnConnected()
        {
            //Some code here
        }
        public override Task OnReconnected()
        {
             //Some code here
        }
        public async Task UpdateStatus(int messageId, int ServerId, StatusType status)
        {
             //Some code here
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            // Dispose the hub lifetime scope when the hub is disposed.
            if (disposing && _hubLifetimeScope != null)
            {
                _hubLifetimeScope.Dispose();
            }

            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

    }
}
```

Thats all the configuration.

As I said in the MVC and API controllers are working well with DI only signalr not connecting from client and failing with the below error.

```
Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.HttpClientException: StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpcUHJvamVjdHNcQk9UUmVwb1xCT1Rcc2lnbmFsclxuZWdvdGlhdGU=?=
  Cache-Control: private
  Date: Sat, 28 Dec 2019 20:43:45 GMT
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
  X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
}
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Http.DefaultHttpClient.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<Get>b__1(HttpResponseMessage responseMessage)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass31_0`2.<Then>b__0(Task`1 t)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper.TaskRunners`2.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<RunTask>b__0(Task`1 t)
```

don't know what did i miss in this configuration.

Comment: You only show the stack trace of the exception. So you have the error message ? Could you attach a debugger to catch the exception and get the full message ?

Comment: The error was not showing in the debugger. After trying to connect to the hub from javascript app the error shows in the console and it was due to the duplicate in Chathub name. so changing the hub name solved the issue. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the Hub name after changing the Hub name to "MyChatHub" every thing worked just fine with dependency injection